# How to make Sass mixin more robust

Tags: css, sass, mixins

## Description

I have the following mixin:

```
@mixin insideBorder ($thickness:2px, $color:black, $alpha:.05) {
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 $thickness rgba($color, $alpha);
}
```

**A.** One way to use it is like this:

`@include insideBorder();`

Which will output:

`box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);`

**B.** I can also use it like this:

`@include insideBorder(5px, red);`

Which will output:

`box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);`

## Problems

However, if I only want to change the color, I would do one of these two ways:

1. `@include insideBorder(#369);`
2. `@include insideBorder(red);`

But then I it would compile to:

1. `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #336699 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);`
2. `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 red rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);`

Or if I do this:

- `@include insideBorder(red, .5);`

It shoots an error:

> `Syntax error: $color: 0.5 is not a color for 'rgba'...`

## Question

How can I improve this mixin so that it can take any amount of arguments but depending on the type of argument the mixin "knows" where it belongs?

Comment: Please don't post the solution in your question, that's not how this site works. If you find a solution to your problem then please post it as an answer.

Comment: @RicardoZea In future, please ask why an edit was done if it seems wrong to you rather than asserting your dominance. Doing this will avoid edit wars and other unpleasantness. If there is disagreement, it cannot be resolved through repeated rollbacks: Only discussion. Your response to TinyGiant should have been a justification for the content you wanted back in. What you said instead I cannot agree with at all. Rather than asserting that you know what you're talking about because you've been here for longer, you should give a convincing explanation for your position: Educate people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this sass script i made & improved by @Eric M Suzanne

### **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/69864073c9a9e6b2a580cdf2b0d7ed97/)**

```
$insideBorderThickness: 2px !default;
$insideBorderColor: black !default;
$insideBorderAlpha: .05 !default;

@mixin insideBorder($values...) {
    $borderThickness: $insideBorderThickness;
    $borderColor: $insideBorderColor;
    $borderAlpha: $insideBorderAlpha;

    @each $value in $values {
        @if type_of($value) == number {
            @if unit($value) == "" {
                $borderAlpha: $value;
            } @else {
                $borderThickness: $value;
            }
        } @else if type_of($value) == color {
            $borderColor: $value;
        }
    }

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 $borderThickness rgba($borderColor, $borderAlpha);
}
```

Then you can use @include like this:

```
@include insideBorder();
```

OR

```
@include insideBorder(20px);
```

OR

```
@include insideBorder(blue);
```

OR

```
@include insideBorder(.6);
```

OR

```
@include insideBorder(3em, orange, .5);
```

**LOGIC:**

- First default values are defined for the box-shadow.
- When insideBorder() mixin is used it will assign the default values to inner variables (to avoid default values getting changed on each call of the mixin).
- Next it will check if the value type is "number" & assign it to alpha variable & if the type is number with any other measurement unit like em-px-rm, it will be assigned to thickness & if the type is color, it will be assigned to color variable.
- finally it will create the box shadow css depending on the variable values.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for :D. TBH I didn't think it was going to be this complex, hehe. You can clearly tell I'm so new to Sass. I created a demo of this here: **http://jsfiddle.net/aw752/**. Thanks a million Imran!

Comment: Glade i could help, i cant imagine css without sass but i have never made such a complex mixin before :), I have added your demo to the answer.

Comment: Nice work! There are a few cool Sass features you can use to clean this up even more, and make it more flexible at the same time. [I forked the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VS7t/) and made a few adjustments using default settings, variable arguments, and a more lenient if-statement (so you can set your border width using any unit you like).

Comment: @EricMSuzanne In my heart i knew it can somehow become more simple :), I have updated the answer, Thanks Eric.

Comment: Welcome to the world of using Sass logic to build nifty tools! :)

Comment: Hey Imran, I found a problem with this mixin. If the value of the include is left empty (meaning, it would use the default values), it doesn't style anything. Makes sense? Here's a fiddle, look at example 'E': **http://jsfiddle.net/aw752/1/**

Comment: @ricardozea you missed to style the **"e"** class :) ~ in your fiddle you have mistakenly used **"a"** class selector twice in css. Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw752/2/)**

Comment: Shoot, SO hadn't refreshed the comments. I see Eric's answer :). I see that leaving the values empty do work. I have to admit, this complex Sass mixin is way over my head, at the moment at least :p. Thanks Eric and Imran for your help.

Comment: @ImranBughio, oh man, doh! You're right, I fixed it too and it DOES work! :) : http://jsfiddle.net/aw752/4/ - Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I thought that maybe you could add another example on your answer with empty values. Just sayin' :)

Comment: NP, I am glade this helps you :) & sure i am adding it.

Comment: Here's a 'prettier' **[Demo in CodePen](http://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/69864073c9a9e6b2a580cdf2b0d7ed97/)**

Answer (score 1):

your Mixin is fine. Use this technique to include:

```
@include insideBorder($thickness: 3px, $color: black, $alpha: .1);
```

OR ~ change thickness & alpha

```
@include insideBorder($thickness: 3px, $alpha: .1);
```

OR ~ change only alpha

```
@include insideBorder($alpha: .1);
```

This way you are being specific by telling which value will go to which variable.

you can read more **[HERE](http://www.my-html-codes.com/sass-mixins)**

Comment: Thanks Imran but I don't need vendor prefixes added, I'm using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) for that. Pay attention at the values in the compiled CSS in my examples above, they are appearing in the wrong spot. BTW, your `@include` declaration has a typo and it's incorrectly stated, you're missing the mixin name: `@inlucde (inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05));`.

Comment: ops sorry, btw i have edit my answer to match with what you want check it out

Comment: No problem Imran. Your first example is exactly like mine above. The other two examples are taking properties out and that's not something I want to do, otherwise I would just use the `box-shadow` property directly without a mixin, and that defeats this purpose. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, so i have added another answer which works a lot on mixin side but let's you write less on @include side ~ check it out.